# GPS labels are overlaping in artoolkit ios

Tags: ios, gps, location, artoolkit

I am using `ARToolkit` sdk for location based AR for displaying `geolocation` point on the 
camera. I have implemented this sdk for ios and I have one problem that is two `gps` points which are in same direction is overlapping on each other. How to resolve this problem please help me.

I have some little changes in `AugmentedRealityController.m` class in `updateLocations` method. According to distance i am adjusting label height on the on the screen, but problem is not resolved, how to make a gap between two overlapped marker.

```
if ([item distanceFromOrigin]>= 50 && [item distanceFromOrigin]<= 100) {
                 scaleFactor = 1.2;
                loc.y = loc.y - 20;               
            }
            else if ([item distanceFromOrigin]>= 100 && [item distanceFromOrigin]<= 150) {
                scaleFactor = 0.8;
                loc.y = loc.y - 50;

            }
            else if ([item distanceFromOrigin]>= 150 && [item distanceFromOrigin]<= 200) {
                scaleFactor = 0.6;
                loc.y = loc.y - 80;
            }
            else if ([item distanceFromOrigin]>= 200 && [item distanceFromOrigin]<= 300) {
                scaleFactor = 0.6;
                 loc.y = loc.y - 100;

            }
            else if ([item distanceFromOrigin]>= 300 && [item distanceFromOrigin]<= 400) {
                scaleFactor = 0.6;
                loc.y = loc.y - 120;
            }
            else if ([item distanceFromOrigin]>= 400 && [item distanceFromOrigin]<= 500) {
                scaleFactor = 0.5;
            }
            else if ([item distanceFromOrigin]>= 500 && [item distanceFromOrigin]<= 600) {
                scaleFactor = 0.5;
            }
            else if ([item distanceFromOrigin]> 500)
            {
               scaleFactor = 0.5;
            }
            [markerView setFrame:CGRectMake(loc.x - width / 2.0, loc.y -[item radialDistance]/100, width, height)];
            //            [markerView setFrame:CGRectMake(loc.x - width / 2.0, loc.y, width, height)];
            [markerView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Please help me if anybody have an idea about how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of the callout collision by making some changes in your code.

1) In `AugmentedRealityViewController` there is `updateLocations` method, go into `if` condition and

```
if (!([markerView superview])) {
[[self displayView] insertSubview:markerView atIndex:1];
[self listSubviewsOfView:markerView]; // retrive the subviews from the markerview which is display on the camera screen...
}
```

this condition is `updatelocation` method and i call the `listSubviewsOfView` method, that is used for retriving `subview` from `superView`.

```
(void)listSubviewsOfView:(UIView *)view {

// Get the subviews of the view
NSArray *subviews = [view subviews];

// Return if there are no subviews
if ([subviews count] == 0) return;

for (UIView subview in subviews) {
if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {

UIImageView *myLabel = (UIImageView *)subview;
myLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
if (myLabel.tag == 1)
{
numberOfImageView++;
CGRect rect = myLabel.frame;
rect.origin.y = 0+numberOfImageView50;
myLabel.frame = rect;
}

}
// List the subviews of subview
[self listSubviewsOfView:subview];
}
}

//there is variable numberOfImageView. declare in .h file 
int numberOfImageView;

//and do one thing in else condition of the updateLocation Method , set the "numberOfImageView" to zero.
else 
if ([markerView superview])
{

  [markerView removeFromSuperview];
   numberOfImageView =0;
}
```

then compile and run

Comment: this code will adjust image but when you will touch on the image it will not touchable.

Answer (score 0):

In your AugmentedRealityViewController's UpdateLocation method do some changes 
you can calculate the difference between two marker view and then set the value y position of the marker.

```
for (ARGeoCoordinate *item in [self coordinates]) {
 UIView *markerView = [item displayView];
if ([self shouldDisplayCoordinate:item]) {
 CGPoint loc = [self pointForCoordinate:item];
            CGFloat scaleFactor = SCALE_FACTOR;

            if ([self scaleViewsBasedOnDistance]) 
                scaleFactor = scaleFactor - [self minimumScaleFactor]*([item radialDistance] / [self maximumScaleDistance]);

            float width  = [markerView bounds].size.width  * scaleFactor;
            float height = [markerView bounds].size.height * scaleFactor;
if ([item distanceFromOrigin]>0) {
            float difference = [item distanceFromOrigin]-prevLoc;

        if ((difference>0 &&difference<200) || ( difference < 0 && difference>(-200))) {
                            [markerView setFrame:CGRectMake(loc.x - width / 2.0, loc.y-difference, width, height)];

        }
    prevLoc = [item distanceFromOrigin];
        }
}
else if ([markerView superview])
{
  [markerView removeFromSuperview];
}
}
```

prevLoc is the float type variable declare in the .h file and initialise to zero in the init method.

it will manage the marker in order to y position.